# Getting error: [Errno 10053] while trying to send a file in http response

Tags: python, http, basehttpserver

Am trying to send a big file in http response by writing into `wfile` variable of `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` in Python, when I am trying to do that I am ending with the below exception in my Python code always.

`error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your machine`

Can any one help me to resolve this?? why am getting the error?
If the way am sending large file in HTTP response is not the good one, please suggest where I can refer.

Thanks in advance!!!

```
import os
import urlparse
import BaseHTTPServer
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn
import urlparse

class Handler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.handle(self)

    def sendError(self, errorCode, errorMessage):
        self.send_response(errorCode, errorMessage)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/plain")
        self.send_header("Content-Length", str(len(errorMessage)))
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(errorMessage)

    def do_GET(self):
        scm, netloc, path, params, query, fragment = urlparse.urlparse(self.path, 'http')
        if path.find(".ld") > 0:
            filename = path.rpartition("/")[2]
            try:
                with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
                    self.send_response(200, "Ok")
                    self.send_header("Content-type","application/octet-stream")
                    total_size = os.path.getsize(filename)
                    self.send_header("Content-Length", total_size)
                    self.end_headers()
                    self.wfile.write(f.read())
            except IOError:
                self.sendError(404, "Not Found")

class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer):
    def __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, bind_and_activate=True):
        BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer.__init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, bind_and_activate)

def main():
    Handler.close_connection = 0
    Handler.protocol_version = 'HTTP/1.1'
    global httpd
    httpd = ThreadedHTTPServer(("", 8900), Handler)
    httpd.daemon_threads = True
    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Error Trace:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('172.24.128.21', 19418)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 593, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 649, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "simple.py", line 10, in handle
    BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.handle(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 342, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 310, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 476, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote ho
st
```

Comment: I would be nice if you actually provided a runnable snippet of code... which is not to say you should paste your entire code but a simplified/reduced version of your code that anyone can copy-paste into a `.py` file and run, in order to help diagnose your issue; see http://sscce.org

Comment: I have added my runnable snippet. can you help me to resolve this.. the file i am trying to transfer is .LD file which is size of 60,000kb

Comment: Please paste the part of the code that is necessary to reproduce the problem, not your entire project; see http://sscce.org; Also, you can just amend the existing snippet, not keep adding stuff to your post.

Comment: this is the simple code to reproduce the problem, may be some of the import modules may useless. the snippet inside the method do_GET() is causing the problem

Comment: So then remove everything that is not related to the problem, including the useless imports.

Comment: i removed all the useless imports and simplified the code

Comment: OK, good; now some comments: there is no need to override methods if the only thing they're doing is delegating to the superclass. Also, `except: pass` is always a very bad idea; also, not sure what you meant with the line where you set `Content-Type` to be what it already is. —in any case, I've somewhat cleaned up your code accordingly.

Comment: P.S. did you actually try that code before you put it up here? Or is it so hard to do some work to help others solve your problem?

Comment: Please post the error traceback of the error you're getting.

Comment: you can now see the correct code, after changing the correct content type.Its been added wrongly. the latest one is tested and it is runnable

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I tried your code after cleaning it up a bit:

```
    def do_GET(self):
        _, _, path, _, _, _ = urlparse.urlparse(self.path, 'http')
        if path.find(".ld") > 0:
            filename = path.rpartition("/")[2]
            try:
                with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
                    self.send_response(200, "Ok")
                    self.send_header("Content-type", self.headers.getheader("Content-type", ""))
                    total_size = os.path.getsize(filename)
                    self.send_header("Content-Length", total_size)
                    self.end_headers()
                    self.wfile.write(f.read())
            except IOError:
                self.sendError(404, "Not Found")
```

I put a `foo.pl` file in the same folder; then, when doing `curl http://localhost/foo.pl`, I get a nice response with the content of the file, and no errors whatsoever.

I must also say that it looks like you're just trying to get the file name without the path part using `path.rpartition("/")[2]`, but for that, you should just use `os.path.basename`:

```
>>> os.path.basename('foo/bar/baz.pl')
'baz.pl'
```

Also, `path.find(".ld") > 0` should probably be `path.endswith(".ld")` instead.

**EDIT:** to support large files (efficiently):

```
CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 100  # 100kB chunks
while True:
    chunk = f.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
    if not chunk:
        break
    self.wfile.write(chunk)
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i will change these. where i can add the error trace of mine.. in the original post?

Comment: When i try to download a small file using my code its working.. problem is with large files only. Am getting the exception when i try to download the file type of .ld of size 60,000kb

Comment: @user2153447: I've amended the answer to explain how to handle large files (e.g. 60MB).

Comment: :Thanks!! I tried that one already. Am able to transfer the file successfully, But also am getting the same exception. Is it a kind of negligible one?

Comment: @DineshKumar: so my change helped make the file transfer itself work, but the exception is still there *after* a successful/complete file download?

Comment: yeah your changed helped me to transfer, i tried similar code like sending as chunks before itself. But i got the same exception before and now also